# How to install only Joomla site pages without administrator pages on a server

Tags: joomla, hosting, administrator

I have prepared my simple html website on my local pc. Now I want to put only the main website pages without administrator backend pages on server. I tried several queries on google but of no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla pages are not 'simple html pages,' they are complex .php scripts. You can't leave the administrator backend pages off the server because they are required by Joomla to function.  What you can do, however, is modify your server configuration (I use Apache2) to make the administrator directory inaccessible to web browsers. I do this routinely on my Joomla sites within a virtualhost block.

```
# Deny access to Joomla administrator directory
<Directory "/your/joomla/install/administrator/">
Order Allow,Deny
</Directory>
```

You'll need to comment this out and restart Apache to access the administrator console.